# how to do average in csv file in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

Is there any function in matlab which automatically do average of data stored in csv file and store that average value in other csv file.
this is my data stored in csv file

> 156.465902
>   416.337235
>   113.321306
>   88.751015
>   816.503289
>   104.757462
>   99.555698
>   210.75769
>   79.555543
>   131.261252
>   327.92057
>   120.064075
>   94.364211
>   167.277443
>   84.036572
>   188.522951
>   599.428593
>   275.750197
>   246.108917
>   1477.377321
>   140.480201

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) and [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) to achieve what you want.

```
values = dlmread('input_file.csv');
m = mean(values(:));
dlmwrite('output_file.csv', m);
```

You can also append the value to output file like this:

```
dlmwrite('output_file.csv', m, '-append');
```

Comment: @vishwajoshi Do not hesitate in accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: if i want to append that data in another csv file in first colomn first row, how to do? for example in 1.csv file stored data is  
1223.594406
126.273871
15.794303
 i want to add value stored in output_file.csv

Comment: Thank you again sir your ans help me lot.